# Strava v3 api JS GET data

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am trying to get data using the [strava v3 api](http://strava.github.io/api/). I am very new to JS. I copied the example XMLHttpRequest code, but all I get is an empty string returned. If I go to the link [manually](https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=1&access_token=83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9) in the browser, it works fine. I've also tried this using jquery and I get the same thing.

```
function reqListener() {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        };

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.onload = reqListener;
        oReq.open("get", "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=1&access_token=83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9", true);
        oReq.send();
```

Any ideas?

Edit: with jquery. Still doesn't work

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="hello">hello</span>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=1&access_token=83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9&callback=?", function(data) {
                    $('#hello').html(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

From their documentation:

> **JSON-P callbacks**
>
> Specify the ?callback=function_name parameter to request a JSONP
>   compatible response. This is compatible with JavaScript libraries such
>   as jQuery.

So I'd suggest you use [jQuery to trigger a JSONP request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) to them:

```
$.getJSON( "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=1&access_token=yourAccessToken&callback=?", function (data) {
  // your code in here
});
```

---

**Edit**

As per comment below: The `callback=?` in this form (no replacement of the `?`) signals to jQuery, that this is a JSONP request. jQuery itself will change the `?` to some function name for the callback, which basically executes the function you pass to `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't get it to work though... Edited original post.

Comment: @stuppie Currently returns an "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request" error for me. And the returned JSONP says something about "not allowed", so I guess currently you can't use JSONP and hence use the API directly on client side. You might be able to retrieve the data on the server, though.

Comment: How do I do this? If I simply go to that url in the browser, it works. Is there a way to just grab that text?

Comment: @stuppie You can use any server side language you like. Look at the respective documentation, how to execute a GET request in that language.

Comment: One thing that tripped me out here is that the question mark after the callback (callback=?) should remain in place - I originally interpreted the answer above to mean that I should replace the ? with the name of my own callback. This is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), so [**use jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get( "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?per_page=1&access_token=83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9", function (results) {
  // use returned results
});
```